# Flutter problem: How to call images and links when I search

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello im Flutter beginner and i was making a search field.

However I don't know how to pop up the corresponding image when I click on the searched item.
What I want to make is in this image: [my problem with Flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooH25.jpg)

And this is my code:

```
class _SearchFieldBodyState extends State<SearchFieldBody> {
  @override
  String searchValue = '';
  final List<String> _suggestions = [
    'a1',
    'a2',
    'a3',
    'a4',
    'a5',
    'a6',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
            appBar: EasySearchBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0,
                title: const Text('Search Field'),
                iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: kPrimaryColor),
                onSearch: (value) => setState(() => searchValue = value),
                suggestions: _suggestions),
            body: Center(child: switchproduct(_suggestions))));
    //body: Center(child: Text('Value: $searchValue'))));
  }
}

// and this is my failed code
Widget switchproduct(_suggestions) {
  switch (_suggestions) {
    case 'a1':
      return Image.asset("assets/images/a1.jpg"); 
...
  }
}
```

I tried to use the switch statement, but it didn't help at all.
Well im using a searching package, the contents of the list are printed well...
but I really don't know how to put image in proper items. Anyone could help will be very appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the impression you are not using the right value in your switch.

First, you should add a type for your `switchproduct` method parameter.

Second, you should do your swith on `searchValue` which is the value you update in your `setState`.

So, if I understand this correctly, you could directly write :

```
...
body: Center(child: switchproduct(searchValue))));
...

Widget switchproduct(String searchValue) {
  switch (searchValue) {
    case 'a1':
      return Image.asset("assets/images/a1.jpg"); 
...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me, RDO. I solved the code as you told me, but an error 'The matched value type 'List<String>' can never be equal to this constant of type 'String' occurs. This always pop up when i try to match either data type. Is there any way I can solve it?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I forgot to replace the `_suggestions ` with `searchValue` in the switch

Comment: I see, thanks a lot : )) You helped me understand and study the code. ♡